# Eigen library + Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks, eigen

Trying to use Code::blocks with the library Eigen. Using windows vista. With some help from a forum I got this command to compile a sample program:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\eigen>g++ -I C:\Users\Me\Desktop\eigen\eigen3 
-o test2.exe C:\Users\Me\Desktop\eigen\test.cpp
```

But if I `cd` anywhere else (other than my folder containing test.cpp) and try to build, I get a permission denied error.

On code blocks I started a new project and went to Settings->Compiler->Linker settings->Link libraries-> and added C:\Users\Me\Desktop\eigen

And also added the same link under build options. I got this error:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\GUI\vector\main.cpp|2|fatal error: 
Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory|
```

The pages I followed were:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html

https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/blob/master/docs/install_eigen.md

Answer (score 0):

As eigen has already stated, all you have to do is copy the headers from the eigen folder to the include folder of your compiler (or just make sure your compiler can find your eigen folder).

Just copy the entire Eigen folder from drive/(where eigen is)/eigen/ to the include folder of code blocks in CodeBlocks\MinGW\include.

After that, all you have to do is make sure in Settings->Compiler in the Search directories tab, the compiler tab has the location to include and linker tab to lib, and the same goes for your build options.

There is absolutely no use of adding the Eigen folder to link libraries option of the linker tab, since Eigen has no libraries and works only with headers.